Preprocessing a large dataset with tf.layers.TextVectorization gives Memory Errors
I have around 300k files, which is around 9GB of medical literature.
My goal is to establish the frequency of ALL tokens in the dataset and serialize them to a csv file (token, frequency).
To achieve this, I used layers.TextVectorization with output_mode='count'.
Adapting the huge dataset went fine, but when retrieving the vocabulary I got:
2024-04-20 22:38:56.832518: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-20 22:38:56.833545: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Discoverd 323719 files
Finished adapting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(file_location_of_source_code)", line 55, in <module>
    inverse_vocab = vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary()
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\src\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\text_vectorization.py", line 487, in get_vocabulary
    return self._lookup_layer.get_vocabulary(include_special_tokens)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\src\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\index_lookup.py", line 385, in get_vocabulary
    self._tensor_vocab_to_numpy(vocab),
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\src\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\string_lookup.py", line 416, in _tensor_vocab_to_numpy
    [tf.compat.as_text(x, self.encoding) for x in vocabulary]
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\src\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\preprocessing\string_lookup.py", line 416, in <listcomp>
    [tf.compat.as_text(x, self.encoding) for x in vocabulary]
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1

Relevant piece from my code:
files_root = pathlib.Path(r"directoryname")
files = tf.data.TextLineDataset.list_files(str(files_root/'*'))
text_ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(files).filter(lambda x: tf.cast(tf.strings.length(x), bool))
# by default this tokenizes elements by new line
# we use dataset class bec it is for large amounts of data

# Converting the vocab to integer indexes, wrt their frequency
vectorize_layer = layers.TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    output_mode='count')
# vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds.batch(1024))
print(f"Discoverd {len(files)} files")
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds.batch(1024))
print("Finished adapting")
inverse_vocab = vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary() #<----ERROR 
print("Vocabulary Retrieved, with the len:")
size_vocab = len(inverse_vocab) 
print(size_vocab)

Further, I was planning to combine the frequency arrays for all sequences, the approach worked on considerably smaller datasets:
text_vector_ds = text_ds.batch(1024).prefetch(AUTOTUNE).map(vectorize_layer).unbatch()
print("Finished vectorization")
it = text_vector_ds.as_numpy_iterator()
freq_arr = None
for i, entry in enumerate(text_vector_ds.as_numpy_iterator()):
    if i == 0:
        freq_arr = np.zeros(len(entry))
        freq_arr += entry.astype(int)
    else:
        freq_arr += entry.astype(int)

What could be the solution to this issue? I need the vocabulary in order to map the actual tokens to their frequency.
I am fairly new to tensorflow and keras, any advice or critique to my approach are welcome. I really need some guidance on working with huge datasets. My ultimate goal is to feed them to a neural network (more specific, some skip grams).
Many thanks.

Hi, do you actually use inverse_vocab for smth? Can you consider extracting vocabulary size directly from your layer size_vocab = vectorize_layer.vocabulary_size()

thanks for the question,
Unfortunately most probably you need a bit more memory to fully process your dataset.
As far as I see: vectorize_layer.get_vocabulary() not very well optimized and at some point it keeps several copies of the vocabulary. And it seems that your vocabulary is very large.
Thus the easies solution would be to limit max_tokens in TextVectorization. This will keep only top tokens.
First question
Easies solution would be to limit max_tokens in TextVectorization.
-- possible workaround
In your case I would also consider to extract and save on the disk the vocabulary (unsorted tokens) and later process them separately in another script:
# this is how you can get access to saved tokens
keys, keys_idx = vectorize_layer._lookup_layer.lookup_table.export()

-- possible workaround
Write your own better optimized version of get_vocabulary method:
# better optimized version of get_vocabulary method
def get_vocabulary(lookup_layer):

  # vocabulary is unsorted
  keys, values = lookup_layer.lookup_table.export()
  vocab, indices = (values, keys) if lookup_layer.invert else (keys, values)
  vocab, indices = (
      lookup_layer._tensor_vocab_to_numpy(vocab),
      indices.numpy(),
  )

  # free the memory
  del keys, values 

  # sorting vocabulary by indexes
  p = np.argsort(indices)
  vocab = vocab[p]

  del indices
  return vocab

lookup_layer = vectorize_layer._lookup_layer
vocab = get_vocabulary(lookup_layer)

Second question
As for the second part I would suggest to avoid calling unbatch and would consider processing the mapped data in batches. Maybe something like this:
text_count = text_ds.batch(1024).prefetch(1).map(vectorize_layer)
for batch in text_count:
  freq_batch = batch.numpy().sum(axis=0)
  if i == 0:
      freq_arr = np.zeros(len(freq_batch))
      freq_arr += freq_batch.astype(int)
  else:
      freq_arr += freq_batch.astype(int)

